# Error when using varImp for nnet neural network

Tags: r, r-caret, nnet

I need to use `varImp` function on neural  network model created by nnet method via caret.

The code:

```
#Load Packages
require(quantmod)
require(nnet)
require(caret)

#Creating data
T <- seq(0,20,length=200)                                   
y <- 1 + 3*cos(4*T+2) +.2*T^2 + rnorm(200)                  
dat <- data.frame( y, x1=Lag(y,1), x2=Lag(y,2),x3=Lag(y,3)) 
dat <- dat[4:length(dat[,1]),]
names(dat) <- c('y','x1','x2','x3')

set.seed(100) 
podzial <- createDataPartition(y, p = 3/4, list = FALSE)
zucz<-dat[podzial,]
ztest<-dat[-podzial,]

# Train control
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV",p=0.7)

#Training
model <- train(y ~ x1+x2 , zucz, method='nnet', linout=TRUE, trace=F,maxit=100,skip=T,
           tuneGrid=expand.grid(.size=c(10),.decay=c(0,0.1,0.001,0.0001)),
           trControl = ctrl,
           preProcess = c("range"))

varImp(model,scale=F)
```

When I try to use `varImp` the error occurs:

```
Error in i2h[hidden, input] <- abeta[grep(label, nms, fixed = TRUE)] : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I have done several test with diferent number of neurons. It appears that error occurs when number of neurons (size parameter) is bigger than 9. How to fix it?

Comment: This means that the total length ( `hidden * input`) of the output "region" is not a match for the length of what `abeta` is putting out.  You'll need to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is very clearly a bug in the `caret` package, specifically in the `caret:::GarsonWeights` function. This function tries to decode the coefficient names from your final model. They are

```
names(coef(model$finalModel))
#  [1] "b->h1"   "i1->h1"  "i2->h1"  "b->h2"   "i1->h2"  "i2->h2"  "b->h3"  
#  [8] "i1->h3"  "i2->h3"  "b->h4"   "i1->h4"  "i2->h4"  "b->h5"   "i1->h5" 
# [15] "i2->h5"  "b->h6"   "i1->h6"  "i2->h6"  "b->h7"   "i1->h7"  "i2->h7" 
# [22] "b->h8"   "i1->h8"  "i2->h8"  "b->h9"   "i1->h9"  "i2->h9"  "b->h10" 
# [29] "i1->h10" "i2->h10" "b->o"    "h1->o"   "h2->o"   "h3->o"   "h4->o"  
# [36] "h5->o"   "h6->o"   "h7->o"   "h8->o"   "h9->o"   "h10->o"
```

Here you have 2 input and 10 hidden nodes. The function tries to find the coefficent for input 1 and hidden note 1 by grepping for "i1->h1" with

```
grep("i1->h1",names(coef(model$finalModel)),fixed=T)
# [1]  2 29
```

But as you can see, two columns are returned, both "i1->h1" and "i1->h10". This is why the problem only happens when you get above 9 nodes. So clearly `grep` is not the correct function here. This is what's causing the error you see.

Now, how to fix it. First, we need a corrected version of `GarsonWeights`. So what i'm going to do, is copy the version from `caret` and attempt to replace the `grep` with `match`

```
gw <- caret:::GarsonWeights
body(gw)[[c(7,4,2,4,3,3,3)]] <- quote(match(label,nms))
body(gw)[[c(8,4,2,4,3,3,3)]] <- quote(match(label,nms))
```

Here i'm actually digging into the body of the function and changing just one section. Now this method for fixing a function is very fragile and may change with different versions. I tested this using `caret_6.0-21`.

The second challenge is to get `varImp` to use this updated version of the weights function. Unfortunately we can't directly update the one in the `caret` namespace and the default code explicitly uses that one. So what we're going to need to do, is actually change the `model` object which tells `varImp()` which how to run. If you look at `model$modelInfo$varImp` you can see where it's calling `caret:::GarsonWeights`. We just need to change that to our `gw` function. We can do that with

```
body(model$modelInfo$varImp)[[c(2,3)]]<-quote(gw(object,...))
```

I think this should work. You will need to re-run on every model you get when you run `train()` with `method="nnet"`.

I suggest you contact the `caret` maintainer and report this bug. Feel free to provide a link to this answer for a full description.

Comment: This had previously been fixed in the devel version of the package. It will prob be on CRAN in a week or so.